# Decorators don't work with custom-react-scripts

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react, custom-react-scripts

I read this article:
https://medium.com/@kitze/configure-create-react-app-without-ejecting-d8450e96196a

I followed its instruction and here is my code:
https://github.com/franva/custom-react-scripts

I want to use decorators feature for mobx integration without ejecting, but it just doesn't work even REACT_APP_DECORATORS = true;

Here is the error message:

> ./src/components/ChatRoom.jsx Syntax error:
>   F:/temp/Playground/my-app/src/components/ChatRoom.jsx: Unexpected
>   token (5:0)
>
> 3 | import {observer} from 'mobx-react';
>
> 4 |
>
> > 5 | @observer
> >         | ^
> >       6 | class ChatRoom extends Component {
> >       7 |
> >       8 |     @observable

Comment: It's always easier to configure the environment once you eject the app. Try run `yarn eject` before adding the `babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy` package

Answer (score 1):

The `@decorator` is ES7 syntax, you need the `transform-decorators` plugin to transpile it with babel :

https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-decorators/

Edit: I just saw you want to use it without ejecting, maybe you have to turn `REACT_APP_BABEL_STAGE_0=true` too.

Comment: I did turned on the REACT_APP_BABEL_STAGE_0=true. You can see the source code in my github. Meanwhile, I will try to use transform-decorators.Does it require ejecting project? My intention is not ejecting the project.

Comment: hi, I tried the transform-decorators plugin, but still it's the same error.

Comment: Your code is compiling for me, i think you just need to rebuild your dependencies and maybe upgrade your node version.

Comment: can you please tell me ur node,  npm version?

Comment: Hi , I tried my code again on a different computer, it works. thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in my local computer environment.

I tried my code on a different computer and it works.